# Query that returns data not found in a table

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to do through a direct query what I propose?
I want a query to return the hostname that does not exist in a table when I search through an `IN` keyword.

```
select * from cpus_view where hostname in ('HostnameEXIST', 'hostnameNOEXIST')
```

I want to make a query that returns the `HostnameNOEXITS`, which is the one that does not exist in the table `vista_cpus`

Do you know how to do a direct query and do not have to do anything stored procedure type, etc?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: `hostname *not* in`?

Comment: `SELECT 'hostnameNOEXIST' EXCEPT SELECT hostname FROM cpus_view` will return `hostnameNOEXIST` if it does not exist in the table, and nothing otherwise. You can extend this to multiple values with `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('hostnameEXIST'), ('hostnameNOEXIST')) hosts(n) EXCEPT ...`

Answer (score 1):

One way is with a derived table and row constructors:

```
SELECT hostnames.hostname
FROM (VALUES('HostnameEXIST'), ('hostnameNOEXIST')) AS hostnames(hostname)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM cpus_view 
    WHERE cpus_view.hostname = hostnames.hostname
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your list as a dataset and then `left join` your table:

```
SELECT v.hostname, c.Column1, c.Column2 --etc
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('HostnameEXIST'),
        ('hostnameNOEXIST')
) v(hostname)
    LEFT JOIN cpus_view c ON c.hostname = v.hostname
-- WHERE c.hostname IS NULL -- Activate this condition if you need only "hostnameNOEXIST" values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join then filter out the records without a match.

```
SELECT * FROM cpus_view AS A
    LEFT JOIN vista_cpus AS B ON A.hostname = B.hostname
        WHERE A.hostname IN ('HostnameEXIST','hostnameNOEXIST') AND B.hostname IS NULL
```